# Shopify Liquid: Consecutive for loops iterating out of order

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to modify a Shopify theme that displays products by looping through the collection. I wanted to display the out-of-stock products after the rest, so I created a for loop to iterate through in-stock items, and then another to iterate through out-of-stock items. However, there is always one in-stock listing that appears after all the out-of-stock listings.

In an attempt to debug this I added html tags inside the product listing and before and after the liquid loop.

How could the listing have the "avail" comment but be after the "END Available Products" comment?

> Red: Available Products
>
> Blue: Unavailable Products

[image: Annotated image of chrome inspector]

```
<div id="product-loop" {% if settings.collection-sidebar %}class="desktop-10 tablet-5 mobile-3"{% endif %}>
  {% assign products-per-row = settings.products-per-row %}

  <!-- Available Products -->
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    {% assign outofstock = true %}
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
        {% if variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
            {% assign outofstock = false %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  
    {% if outofstock == false %}
      {% if current_tags != null %}
          <!-- Tag section removed for brevity -->
      {% endif %}
  
      <div class="product-index {% if template == 'index' and settings.homepage-product-display == 'carousel' %}{% else %}{% if products-per-row == "6" %}desktop-2{% cycle ' first', '', '', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "4" %}desktop-3{% cycle ' first', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "3" %}desktop-4{% cycle ' first', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "5" %}desktop-fifth{% cycle ' first', '', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "2" %}desktop-6{% cycle ' first', ' last' %}{% endif %} tablet-half mobile-half{% endif %}" data-alpha="{{ product.title }}" data-price="{{ product.price }}">
        <!-- avail -->
        {% include 'product-listing' %}
        {% include "panda-swatch" %}
      </div>
  
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <!-- END Available Products -->
  
  <!-- Unavailable Products -->
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    {% assign outofstock = true %}
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
        {% if variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
        {% assign outofstock = false %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  
    {% if outofstock == true %}
      {% if current_tags != null %}
          <!-- Tag section removed for brevity -->
      {% endif %}
  
      <div class="product-index {% if template == 'index' and settings.homepage-product-display == 'carousel' %}{% else %}{% if products-per-row == "6" %}desktop-2{% cycle ' first', '', '', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "4" %}desktop-3{% cycle ' first', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "3" %}desktop-4{% cycle ' first', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "5" %}desktop-fifth{% cycle ' first', '', '', '', ' last' %}{% elsif products-per-row == "2" %}desktop-6{% cycle ' first', ' last' %}{% endif %} tablet-half mobile-half{% endif %}" data-alpha="{{ product.title }}" data-price="{{ product.price }}">
        <!-- no avail -->
        {% include 'product-listing' %}
        {% include "panda-swatch" %}
      </div>
  
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <!-- END Unavailable Products -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: That's a tricky one. Do you think there may be some JS code included that pushes certain product to the bottom of the page, regardless of loop settings?

Comment: @LukaszFormela Hmm.. That's a good thought. I'll look into it.

Comment: @LukaszFormela Your suggestion led me to find the answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to pagination altering the order of the product listings *after* in-stock / out-of-stock loops generated html. Fixing the issue required altering the pagination method.